# IOS/Android Contact-less Payment Emulation - Greggs

Tags: android, ios, nfc, payment, contactless-smartcard

I know that from IOS11 you can access the [CoreNFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) to read NDEF tags. I also know that it allows developer access to read mode only.

What I'm wondering is how Greggs (the bakery chain) have enabled contactless payment via their prepaid app? The process goes:

1. Prepay app
2. Pay with app, via contactless, against [spirepayments](https://www.spirepayments.com/) payment point
3. App deducts credit from in-app balance

This functionality is available for both IOS and Android users. I know a little about EMV specifications and it seems to me that either Greggs have registered themselves as a valid banking merchant, with the required transaction certificates, or the spirepayment hardware is specially configured to allow non-standard NFC payments (specifically from the Greggs app).

Either way, I can't figure out how given IOS CoreNFC only allows reading, it's *sending* data to the payment point?

Comment: I want to ask the same. Did you find an answer? Can we use NFC for payments in IOS. As android gives full access with NFC-Card Emulation mode.

Comment: @RamshaS No i didn't sorry. The best I could work out is that the app used NFC to communicate a valid app-id, and that the money was deducted later.